# How do I invoke the “--enable-stdcall-fixup” option?

Tags: haskell

While building a DLL under Windows I get the following output:

```
Linking main.exe ...
Warning: resolving _findPeaksWrapper by linking to _findPeaksWrapper@16
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Creating library file: HSdll.dll.a
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
```

It’s not clear to me where I should be placing the `--enable-stdcall-fixup` flag. Putting it into the `ghc-options` field of my .cabal file gives a GHC error, while putting it into `cc-options` or `ld-options` seems not to do anything (the warnings are still displayed). Where should this flag go?

Comment: Can you use `cabal -v` to find out which program is running when these messages are printed?

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried `cabal -v2` and it doesn’t show anything more than what I posted; right after that it says “Building C Sources…”.

Comment: Maybe `-optl--enable-stdcall-fixup` or `-optl-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` (depending on how ghc works on Windows).

Comment: @ReidBarton Adding `-optl-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` to the `ghc-options` worked, thanks! Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling indicates that `--enable-stdcall-fixup` is an option to ld. There are a few different pathways by which cabal's final link step can happen, but in your case it is apparently

```
Cabal -> ghc (link step) -> gcc -> ld
```

so to match this you must specify

```
ghc-options: -optl-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup
```